# CAAnimation with timeRange - iOS

Tags: ios, core-animation

I need a `CALayer` to appear on screen at a specified time with some  `CAAnimation` ( eg. *fadeIn*) . I want it to stay on the screen for a couple of seconds and then disappear with a `fadeOut` animation.

**Example** : If I have a timeRange as :
`CMTimeRangeMake(start: 3 , end : 5)` I need a `CAAnimation` at the start of 3 seconds and one at the end of  5 seconds .The CALayer must only be present during the duration of the `timeRange`.

I have found a work around to display the `CALayer` so that it appears  at a specified time , however I don't know how to make it stay for a given duration.

```
        // Call this method in   viewDidLoad for quick demo

      func layerAnimation(){

    let box =             CALayer()
    box.frame =           CGRect(x:100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
    box.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
     self.view.layer.addSublayer(box)

    // Animation

    CATransaction.begin()

    let hide = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    hide.duration =  3                               // The Start time for the box to appear in seconds
    hide.fromValue = 0
    hide.toValue =   0
    hide.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    hide.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth

     CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({() -> Void in

        let fadeInFadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeInFadeOut.duration =  0
        fadeInFadeOut.fromValue = 0
        fadeInFadeOut.toValue =   1
        fadeInFadeOut.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        fadeInFadeOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
        fadeInFadeOut.autoreverses = true


        box.add(fadeInFadeOut, forKey: "fadeInFadeOut")
    })
    box.add(hide, forKey: "hide")
    CATransaction.commit()

}
```

I finally want to be able to add titles to a video to make Lyric videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PT2_F-1esPk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want the animation to delay 3 seconds, fade in and then fade out after it has been shown for 2 seconds at full opacity.  If it is supposed to fade immediately just remove the begin time setting inside the completion block.  Give this a try. I am using the beginTime property and also I removed the isRemovedOnCompletion as you should generally try to avoid using that because you don't want to pollute the presentationLayer. I changed the actual animation duration to 0.5 seconds.  This is how long it will take to fully fade in our out.  If you want to change that to something longer you can.

```
// Call this method in   viewDidAppear <-//Please for quick demo
func layerAnimation(){

        let box =             CALayer()
        box.frame =           CGRect(x:100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        box.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(box)

        // Animation

        CATransaction.begin()

        let fadeIn = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeIn.duration =  0.5
        fadeIn.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 3.0 // The Start time for the box to appear in seconds
        fadeIn.fromValue = 0
        fadeIn.toValue =   1
        //makes the animation start from the from value when there is a delay
        fadeIn.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards

        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({() -> Void in
            let fadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            fadeOut.duration =  0.5
            fadeOut.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 2.0 // The Start time for the box to appear in seconds
            fadeOut.fromValue = 1
            fadeOut.toValue =   0
            //makes the animation start from the from value when there is a delay
            fadeOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
            box.add(fadeOut, forKey: "hide")

            //update the model so that it is really hidden. best not to use isRemovedOnCompletion
            box.opacity = 0
        })
        box.add(fadeIn, forKey: "show")
        CATransaction.commit()

    }
```

Comment: I do the same thing all the time.  This guy has a great blog with several great posts on CAAnimations.  Check it out.  http://ronnqvi.st/clear-animation-code/

Comment: I certainly will

Comment: I notice that it  doesn't work when this animation is applied  to a `CALayer` that is a subclass of  `AVSyncronizedLayer` . Do you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: @Tyrone maybe because "AVSynchronizedLayer a subclass of CALayer
 with layer timing that synchronizes with a specific AVPlayerItem.".  I would log the time of the layer when the AVPlayerItem starts...It might be the begin time of the layer + 3.0 of that number

Comment: @Tyrone did you figure it out?

Comment: I'm sorry I took too long to respond. I wanted to get back only when I had a working solution. I need to solidify my  understanding of `CAAnimation` &  timing first . I haven't yet figured it out .

Comment: So I don't understand why it works but apparently , the `AVSynchronizationLayer` will only display the _animated text layer_ if 3 conditions are met: (1) `CATransaction.completionBlock` isn't used (2) `CACurrentMediatime() ` is removed  in entirety. (3)  ` animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false` is used.
Still the desired animation doesn't occur because the `fillMode` property of  `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` conflict with each other. Thus I finally ended up using `CAKeyFrameAnimation`  which did the job.

Comment: @Tyrone thanks for coming back on this. Will put it in the memory bank and will explore if I get there.

Comment: should have come back to you on this Tyrone.  I have actually played in AVFoundation now a bit. So you cannot apply multiple animations on one attribute(ex.Opacity) but you can use keyframes to do fade in fade out.  RemovedOnCompletion has to be false.  You cannot use completionBlocks.  You have to use AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero instead of CACurrentMediaTime.  There are other rules that I am figuring out but they are not listed anywhere